# Синтаксический разбор предложения с условным наклонением и инфинитивом

Tags: conditional, синтаксис

Есть предложение: Перед кем бы ты хотел извиниться?

*ты* -  подлежащее

*хотел бы* - сказуемое

хотел бы что сделать? - *извиниться*

Каким членом предложения является глагол в начальной форме **извиниться**?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! We are happy to help you with your homework, but could you please show us what you have tried so far and why do you think it does not work? Thank you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это часть составного сказуемого.

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/kakoi-chlen-predlozheniya-infinitiv.html#i-1

Comment: Часть составного _глагольного_ сказуемого.